# RecyclerView.Adapter onViewRecycled() not called

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `ViewHolder` that subscribes to a Rx `Observable`. Now I need to dispose the disposable, so I do it in `onViewRecycled()` as I've read its supposed to be for freeing resources, however it **never gets called**, not even on rotation. Is this intended behaviour?

Might it be because I have few items, 5 consisting of 3 viewtypes? `onDetachedFromRecyclerView` gets called, but Id like to subscribe in the constructor, not everytime it gets back onscreen/offscreen

```
public class FeedAdapter {

    onCreateViewHolder ..
    onBindViewHolder..

    @Override 
    public void onViewRecycled(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
        super.onViewRecycled(holder);
        // THIS IS WHAT I HAVE NEVER SEEN GET CALLED
        if (holder instanceof FeaturedBooksHolder) {
            ((FeaturedBooksHolder) holder).dispose();
        }
    }

     static class FeaturedBooksHolder extends BooksHolder {
        private final Disposable mDisposable;


        FeaturedBooksHolder(View itemView, OnBookClickListener listener, AdapterClickListener headerClickListener, Observable<Tuple2<Boolean, NativeAdsManager>> observable) {
            super(itemView, listener, headerClickListener);
            mRecyclerView = findById(itemView, recyclerView);

            BooksAdapter adapter = createAdapter(context, listener);
            UiUtils.initHorizontalRecyclerView(context, mRecyclerView, adapter);

            mDisposable = observable.subscribe(tuple -> {
                adapter.setShowAds(tuple.getFirst());
                adapter.setAdsManager(tuple.getSecond());
            });
        }


        void bindTo(FeaturedBooksFeaturedItem item) {
            super.bindTo(item);
            mImageView.setImageURI(item.getImageUrl());
            mSubtitleTextView.setText(item.getSubtitle());
        }

        void dispose() {
            if (mDisposable != null) mDisposable.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `onViewRecycled` is not for "freeing resources".It is called when the adapter view created is recycled or re-used.

Comment: What do you mean, please? In the docs https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html it says ``"If an item view has large or expensive data bound to it such as large bitmaps, this may be a good place to release those resources."``

Comment: If you read closely, according to the documentation, for `onViewRecycled` to be called, the bounded items view will be recycled by items view not visible. Your recyclerview has 5 items all visible hence the method not being called. This is regardless of your `viewtypes`.

Comment: theyre not all visible, and container is scrollable, thats what confused me, however youre right, if I double the items, onViewRecycled starts getting called

Comment: Maybe because it is called right before sending it to RecycledViewPool? In such cases, I recommend to see source code. You can't rely on implementation stay the same between android versions, but can see to understand what's happenning

Comment: I also would like to know which is the apropriate method to free resources. I also thought its 'inViewRecycled' because of documentation text mentioned above.